# How can I reverse-mount a Canon F/1.4 50 mm for macro photography?

Tags: canon, macro, adapter, reverse-mount

I'd like to experiment with mounting my Canon F/1.4 50 mm lens backwards to experiment with macro photography (on a Rebel Xti).

What kind of gear do I need, and how do I go about it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may want a [coupling ring](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000AB4LV) ($7).  This lets you mount one lens, in reverse, to another lens.  This gives you insane macro capabilities, and very little depth of field.

You will find that focusing takes an extremely long time, and you need to set your aperture on your reversed lens first, mounted normally, before flipping it.
[Not-too-good-example](http://www.flickr.com/photos/reuscam/2414466787/lightbox/)

Comment: That's actually a cool shot - good job! A coupling ring is definitely the way to go if you want to do this.

Comment: That's what I was thinking of - thanks. I guess I need a coupling ring that matches my inner camera diameter on one side, and that matches my lens outer diameter for the other?

Comment: Nope, because the mounting bayonet of a camera body is not the same as the threaded lens end of a typical lens.  If you want to go body directly to a reverse lens, see Marc's answer.  If you want to go body to regular lens to a reversed lens, then you want my answer.

Answer (score 10):

You will need a Reverse Mount Adapter, [here's](http://www.novoflex.com/en/products/macro-accessories/reverse-adapter-eos-retro/) an example. You mount the adapter to the body, then mount the lens and finally you attach the second part of the adapter to the back of your lens.

Comment: Aren't there more inexpensive options, without automatic focus etc.? At that price range, I'd be better off with a real macro lens, no?

Comment: @Bossykena, yes sure, see @reuscam answer or look here: http://haodascreen.com/reversing.aspx.

Comment: @Bossykena: Sure you would, but there's no macro that can do 1:7... That in itself is amazing enlargement. AMAZING is the word. And having AF along with it is just pure bliss. Boy I wish... But it is in did pricey.